# Unable to reference two columns on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

For background, I'm using SQL Server on Azure on Mac.

I first created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE PatientVisits 
(
    PatientKey NCHAR(15),
    VisitDate DATE,
    BloodPressure NCHAR(8),
    Weights DECIMAL(18,0),
    Pulse INT,
    DepressionLevel INT,
    DoctorNotes varchar(MAX) NULL

    PRIMARY KEY (PatientKey, VisitDate)
);
```

And then created this one:

```
CREATE TABLE PatientVisitSymptoms 
(
    PatientKey NCHAR(15),
    VisitDate DATE,
    Sympton VARCHAR(100)

    PRIMARY KEY (PatientKey, VisitDate)

    FOREIGN KEY (PatientKey) REFERENCES PatientVisits (PatientKey),
    FOREIGN KEY (VisitDate) REFERENCES PatientVisits (VisitDate),
);
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'PatientVisits' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__PatientVi__Sympt__44FF419A'.
>
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

I previously tried to use `CONSTRAINT` before the foreign key and that didn't work either. What could be causing that error?

Comment: Pls try this 
`CREATE TABLE PatientVisitSymptoms (
    PatientKey NCHAR(15),
    VisitDate DATE,
    Sympton VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY(PatientKey,VisitDate),
    FOREIGN KEY  (PatientKey, VisitDate) REFERENCES PatientVisits  (PatientKey, VisitDate)
);`

Comment: @user2026504 you need to put that into the answer box, not a comment, for that to happen

Comment: You cannot reference half a primary key - your `PatientVisits` table has `PRIMARY KEY (PatientKey, VisitDate)` - so any foreign key do this table **must also** include **BOTH** those columns

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
CREATE TABLE PatientVisitSymptoms 
(     
   PatientKey NCHAR(15),     
   VisitDate DATE,     
   Symptom VARCHAR(100),     
   PRIMARY KEY(PatientKey,VisitDate),     
   FOREIGN KEY  (PatientKey, VisitDate) REFERENCES PatientVisits  (PatientKey, VisitDate) 
);
```